# How to integrate google sign-in into my android app without SignInButton

Tags: android, google-signin

Hi I'm new to android application development and trying to do something with Oauth and I need nothing more than the basic scope of user name, email, etc.

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in?configured=true

I was following the instructions and managed to succeed but what I want to do is to simplify the process. Are there any ways to make the whole signing-in procedure happen on a pop-up message? In other words I want to show user sign-in request display right at the start of the application without the SignInButton.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And I'd really appreciate it if anyone could tell me how I could retain the info of if the user has signed in already, so once one signs in he/she doesn't have to choose which account to go with again when turning on the app after the first time.

Comment: Just trigger the signIn() method logic shown here when your app starts in onStart() for the first Activity https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/signin/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/signin/SignInActivity.java#L136 and then save the user info into shared prefs and read it then the user re-opens the app later http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: Thanks Steven, I've already managed to solve the problem but you suggest another way. Which could be a good solution if some different problem hits me hard regarding this